# how to import urls.py which is below django project forder

Tags: python, django

I created a django project named `test_pro` with app01 in it. All settings is default  .  I wrote "from test_pro import urls". I get an error

> "django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured:Requested setting
>   INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either
>   define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call
>   settings.configure() before accessing settings."

I don't know what mean it is, the question is when I write "from `test_pro` import settings" run success.

How do I solve the problem?

- django version=2.2
- python interpreter version=3.7.3

This is my forder construction:

```
testpro
    -app01
        -migrations
        -__init__.py
        -admin.py
        -apps.py
        -models.py
        -test.py
        -views.py
        templates
    -test_pro
        -__init__.py
        -settings.py
        -urls.py
        -wsgi.py
    -manage.py
```

Comment: where you are importing urls.py? ... also don't forget to add app01 in your INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: maby i want to import urls.py in app01.views.py  ,beacouse i want to discover all urls param recursion  through ROOT_URLCONF...  also thanks for your comments.

Comment: i already solve it.   must access program through browser  ,but not run single .py file...i was stupid..

Comment: could you add the app in your settings.py

Comment: yes  i do. thanks for your comments